# Бизнес-логика и ее реализация

Tags: java, многопоточность, ооп

[image: у]

Вначале про бизнес-логику. Есть идея программы, часть функций уже реализована, структура (как на картинке) уже создана. Встал вопрос насколько такая структура и идея логики программы вообще применимы, какие в них есть недостатки. Основные действия программы помещаются в `Main` и влезают примерно в 10-50 строчек, которые, по сути, являются приказами для других отделов (инициализация).
Получается, что к `Class 2` и `Class 3` образуются и взаимодействуют только в `Class 1`, а остальные (например `Class10`, `Class25`) даже и не предполагают что такие существуют вовсе, они обращаются только к `Class1`. `Class 1` и `Class 10` `extend Thread` и после инициализации ожидают, когда их вызовут.

**Теперь два главных вопроса:**

**1.** Это вообще возможно? Это первая крупная задача, которая встала передо мной, и я столкнулся с некоторыми сложностями, которые у меня остались, наверно, из-за нехватки знаний. А именно: допустим, я создал объект класса `Class1` (это в `Main`). Теперь я хочу обратиться к нему из класса `Class25`, чтобы получить ответ на вопрос, который решают `Class2` и `Class3`. Как это сделать? Важно - я не хочу создавать директора отдела (`Class1`) в каждом из подклассов, я хочу чтобы он был один, и в будущем был потоком, если это возможно.

**2.** И если это все-таки возможно, то насколько это правильно, почему я не видел такой логики в других программах? Связь GETTER-SETTER сводится к минимуму, а ООП развивается по максимуму.

Comment: Спасибо Regent что привел вопрос к читаемому виду :)

Comment: Надеюсь, что это было не зря, и кто-нибудь таки ответит на вопрос...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень хорошие и глобальные вопросы подняты, но вопросов несколько и ответы могут быть очень большими. Отвечу кратко, просто чтобы направить автора вопроса в нужном направлении для развития.

Надо знать, что существуют разные паттерны программирования, то есть на Java можно писать по разному, в разном стиле. И одну и ту же задачу можно решить разными способами и библиотеками.

В целом, на Java активно используется `Spring`. Знание `Spring` с избытком ответит на оба вопроса - как один из вариантов решения. Если решать эти вопросы без `Spring`, то ответы могут быть другими.

**По вопросам в целом**

Если объект экземпляра `Class1` должен быть один (читать про паттерн `singleton`), то объект создается один раз и используется в других объектах по ссылке.
А как он будет сделан - это уже решать автору.
Вариантов много: сделать `static class Class1` или сделать `Spring @Bean Class1` или руками создать объект `Class1` и передавать в конструкторы других классов по ссылке или через геттеры-сеттеры.

П.С. Также полезно разобраться с понятием `POJO`.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы дали основные наводки куда копать дальше, обязательно займусь этим прямо сейчас!

Comment: Так я погуглил, Spring мне пока не нужен, а вот singleton Отлично подошел, и я его действительно не разбирал раньше. Спасибо это то что надо, вы превосходно ответили на вопрос!

Comment: Согласен, сначала, для понимания, лучше сделать реализацию без Spring. Это даст знание как управлять объектами. Затем, в процессе обучения полезно разобраться со Spring. Откроются интересные способы как решить эту же задачу с меньшим количеством кода. То есть Spring много чего делает за разработчика))